# Deformation of curves around $C$ with fibers that intersect $C$ differently?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, deformation-theory

Let $C$ be a curve in a nice smooth surface $S$. Thus $C$ is Cartier and the normal bundle is $N=O(C)_C$, so that deformations of $C$ should intersect $C$ locally in a divisor that is equivalent to $N$ in $Pic(C)$. In the simple examples I know, along ALL the deformation this property holds (i.e any $C'$ in the deformation intersects $C$ in a divisor that is like $N$). I would like to see an example where this holds only locally; so I want a family of curves in a surface $S$, at time $0$ it's $C$, and for other times, $C_t$ intersect $C$ transversely  in a nonconstant class group divisor (nonconstant along $t$).

Here are my failed attempts at examples in surfaces:

1. If $S = \mathbb{P}^2$, then any deformation will have fibers curve that are the same in $Pic(S)$ and so their intersections with $C$ will be the same. (This is because the degree of the curves along the deformation is constant by flatness, so any time $C'$ is transverse to $C$ the intersection will be the same in the class group).
2. To avoid the problem of 1, we might as well start by searching for a deformation of line bundles that aren't all isomorphic. This can be done via take an elliptic curve $E$, and the family over $E$ of its points (aka line bundles). If we now try to turn this into example we can try taking $S = E x D$ for some $D$, but then the fibers have trivial normal bundles and I don't see how to build a family that has any intersection with some fiber.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're asking. If you understand it precisely from a complex geometry POV, could you explain it in that sense?

Comment: @TabesBridges I want a curve $C$ in a surface $S$, and a deformation of $C$ (so a family of curves that at time $0$ is $C$) so that for different curves in the deformation (i.e fibers along the time) they intersect $C$ differently

Comment: @Andy: "If $S=P^2$, then any deformation will have fibers curve that are the same in $Pic(S)$ and so their intersections with $C$ will be the same." Write down explicit examples and include your argument: Why is this true? Then youll recieve more response.

Comment: @hm2020 sure, added details

Comment: @Andy I don't think this is possible for essentially the same reason as in $\mathbb P^2$, namely that deformations are flat hence fix the Hilbert polynomial (in $\mathbb P^2$ this is determined by the degree), which ultimately governs all of the intersections.

Comment: @TabesBridges It's not true that if $C_1, C_2$ have the same Hilbert polynomial  then they intersect line bundles the same; consider $E \times E$ and take two sieves, they have the Hilbert polynomial but intersect the horizontal sieve differently.

Comment: @Andy what is a sieve? I'm not familiar with that term.

Comment: @TabesBridges like $E \times {p_1}$

Comment: OK, you want linear equivalence as opposed to numerical equivalence. Let me think a bit more about that. Side note due to random curiosity: where is the term "sieve" used? I would refer to such a thing as either a fiber (of projection on the second factor) or a constant section (of projection onto the first).